# Object selection in 3D view not working correctly

Tags: 3d-view, customization, selection-tools

I've been using Blender for a while now and have had no issues with object selection in 3D view. I just got a new computer (Mac Pro) and now object selection in 3D view will sometimes become unresponsive.

Some objects are selectable while others cannot be selected unless selecting them from the Outliner panel. I've tried changing system settings and input settings in Blender preferences to no avail.

If I restart Blender and reopen the file I was working on it will behave normally for a while but will inevitably revert to this broken selection state. I'm a little worried that it has something to do with my new computer because it's a work computer and I'm stuck with it so any insight on how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

I've added a snapshot of my current Blender System setup as well as the specs of my Mac.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe the cause of this was due setting the clipping field too low. I don't remember experiencing this issue before but if I keep my clipping settings high (above an inch) object selection works fine.